# Probability to pass an exam, generalized competition problem

Tags: probability, contest-math

In an exam there are 10 questions. If you answer correctly to a question, you get $1$ point. If you answer incorrectly to a question, you get $-1$ point, or lose a point. If you don't answer to a question, you get $0$ point. You pass the exam if you get at least $7$ points.

A pupil read the questions and estimated that he can surely answer correctly to $6$ questions, and for the rest questions he estimated that he could answer correctly with independent probabilities $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ with $0\leq p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\leq 1,p_1p_2p_3p_4=p$. What kind of strategy he must choose to make sure he takes the optimal strategy to pass the exam with respect to numbers $p_1p_2p_3p_4$?

Is that problem solvable? I mean, I figured out the optimal strategy if a student answers correctly with probability $p$ to each of the four questions. This was in Finnish mathematical competition this year. But in this version one has to given that he answers correctly to four question with probability $p$.

Comment: Means do you want an exact nerical value??

Comment: So all we know is that if said pupil answers all 10 questions, he will have 10 correct answers with probability $p$ and less then 10 correct answers with probability $1-p$?

Comment: Perhaps you mean that each of the remaining four questions can be answered correctly with probability $p$? (independent of any of the others)  Thus, should he just attempt one, he'll pass the test with probability $p$?

Comment: @Abstraction Yes, but less that 10 means 6,7,8 or 9 correct answers in this problem.

Comment: @lulu That version was in the original competition but this version is more general.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I would like to know the strategy for every $p$ with $0\leq p\leq 1$.

Comment: More general?  It just seems incomplete...we only know the probability of success for one strategy.  If we assume independence we could back out the probability per question but that assumption would just be a guess.

Comment: Intuitively it makes no sense to answer an even number of questions, and the answer is affected by whether $0 \lt p \lt \frac12$ or $\frac12 \lt p \lt 1$

Comment: @curious Then you have only *two* choices you know anything about: answer 6 questions (probability to pass $0$) or answer 6+$n$ questions (probability to pass at least $p$ and we know nothing about how it changes for different $n$). Basically, for any $n_1 \neq n_2$ I can add another constraint (not contradicting your condition) so that answering 6+$n_1$ questions is no worse than 6+$n_2$. Answering 10 questions is never better than answering 9, but that's it.

Comment: I think the question needs clarification.  As the posted solution shows, most readers (including myself) assume that $p$ refers to a probability of getting a single question right (and people are inclined to assume independence, though you don't specify that anywhere in the question).

Comment: I agree with @lulu, the question is not clear.

Comment: Hmm. Does it make sense for looking an optimal strategy if pupil answers to the rest of the questions with probabilities $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ with $0\leq p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\leq1$ and $p_1p_2p_3p_3p_4=p$ and chooses the strategy that depends on the values $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$?

Comment: If you specify independence (or specify the joint distributions) then, yes.  That's a well posed problem.  Crudely speaking, I expect you'll be more inclined to answer three questions if the $p_i$ are greater than $\frac 12$, but the details need sorting out.  It's just a case by case calculation.

Comment: To clarify:  sort the probabilities as $p_1≥p_2≥p_3≥p_4$.  Then one strategy is to simply answer $\#1$.  The other is to answer the first three.  You'll get a polynomial inequality in three variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WLOG sort those $p$ in descending order such that $p_1\geq p_2 \geq p_3 \geq p_4$. Denote the $X_i$ be the binary random variable corresponding to $p_i$, i.e.

$$\Pr\{X_i = 1\} = p_i, \Pr\{X_i = -1\} = 1 - p_i$$

We need to select the optimal number $n$ such that to the passing probability is maximized:

$$ p(n) = \Pr\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \geq 1\right\}, n = 1, 2, 3, 4$$

It is trivial that answering $0$ question will fail surely, and choosing the questions with the largest $p_i$ will dominate other choices for the same number $n$

Then we see

$$p(1) = \Pr\{X_1 = 1\} = p_1$$

$$p(2) = \Pr\{X_1 + X_2 = 2\} = p_1p_2 \leq p(1)$$

$$\begin{align*} 
p(3) & = \Pr\{X_1 + X_2 + X_3 = 3\} + \Pr\{X_1 + X_2 + X_3 = 1\} \\ 
&= p_1p_2p_3 + p_1p_2(1 - p_3) + p_1p_3(1 - p_2) + p_2p_3(1 - p_1) \\
&= p_1(p_2p_3 + p_2 - p_2p_3 + p_3 - p_2p_3 - p_2p_3) + p_2p_3 \\
&= p_1(p_2 + p_3 - 2p_2p_3) + p_2p_3
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*} 
p(4) & = \Pr\{X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4 = 4\} + \Pr\{X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4 = 2\} \\ &= p_1p_2p_3p_4 + \left[p_1p_2p_3(1-p_4) + \Pr\{X_1+X_2+X_3 = 1\}p_4\right]\\
&= p_1p_2p_3 + \Pr\{X_1+X_2+X_3 = 1\}p_4 \\
&\leq p(3) \end{align*}$$

It reduces to compare $p(1)$ and $p(3)$.

$$ \begin{align*}  p(1) \geq p(3) 
& \iff p_1 \geq p_1(p_2 + p_3 - 2p_2p_3) + p_2p_3  \\
& \iff p_1 \geq \frac {p_2p_3} {1 + 2p_2p_3 - p_2 - p_3} 
= \frac {p_2p_3} {(1 - p_2)(1 - p_3) + p_2p_3}  
\end{align*}$$

So if $(p_1, p_2, p_3)$ satisfy the above inequality, then choose $n = 1$; otherwise choose $n = 3$

Answer (score 0):

The pupil needs to calculate the expected number of points that he/she could gain/lose when:

- Answering $\color\red1$ out of the $4$ remaining questions: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\color\red1}(2n-\color\red1)\cdot\binom{\color\red1}{n}\cdot(p)^n\cdot(1-p)^{\color\red1-n}$
- Answering $\color\red2$ out of the $4$ remaining questions: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\color\red2}(2n-\color\red2)\cdot\binom{\color\red2}{n}\cdot(p)^n\cdot(1-p)^{\color\red2-n}$
- Answering $\color\red3$ out of the $4$ remaining questions: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\color\red3}(2n-\color\red3)\cdot\binom{\color\red3}{n}\cdot(p)^n\cdot(1-p)^{\color\red3-n}$
- Answering $\color\red4$ out of the $4$ remaining questions: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\color\red4}(2n-\color\red4)\cdot\binom{\color\red4}{n}\cdot(p)^n\cdot(1-p)^{\color\red4-n}$

Then, the pupil should choose the best result and operate accordingly.

---

**Correction (based on the discussion below with @Henry):**

For each $n\in[1,4]$, the pupil needs to calculate the probability of answering more than $\frac12n$ of the remaining questions correctly, choose the option with the highest probability and act accordingly:

---

When choosing $1$ question, the probability of answering it correctly:

$$p$$

---

When choosing $2$ questions, the probability of answering them correctly:

$$p^2$$

---

When choosing $3$ questions, the probability of answering at least $2$ of them correctly:

$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{3}\binom3n\cdot(p)^n\cdot(1-p)^{3-n}$$

---

When choosing $4$ questions, the probability of answering at least $3$ of them correctly:

$$\sum\limits_{n=3}^{4}\binom4n\cdot(p)^n\cdot(1-p)^{4-n}$$

Comment: Except you are not trying to maximise the expected number of points; you are trying to maximise the probability of $7$ or more points

Comment: @Henry: Isn't that the purpose to begin with, as described in the question? The pupil already has $6$ correct answers, and simply needs the highest expectation for the remaining $4$ questions. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: You are missing that $+1$ point is very valuable, $+2, +3,+4$ just as valuable as $+1$, while $0,-1,-2,-3$ are equally bad.

Comment: @Henry: Yes, but since all we want is $+1$ point, shouldn't we strive for the highest expectation, thus increasing our chances of getting (at least) that $+1$ point? I mean, the question doesn't state that it "costs any extra" to answer all questions (if necessary).

Comment: Suppose $p=\frac9{10}$.  If you answer one more question then your probability of passing is $0.9$ and your expected number of points is $6.8$. If instead you answer two more questions, your probability of passing falls to $0.81$ because you lose a point for a wrong answer, even though your expected number of points has risen to $7.6$.

Comment: @Henry: I don't quite get what you're saying. When answering $1$ question, my expected gain is $0.9$ points. How come you get $6.8$ by adding $0.9$ to $6$??? Also, how did you get to $0.81$? With $p=0.9$, the expected number of points gained for $2$ questions is $1.6$.

Comment: You lose a point for a wrong answer.  So if you answer a $7$th question, your expected result is $6+1\times p -1 \times (1-p)$ which for $p=\frac9{10}$ gives an expected number of points of $6+0.9-0.1=6.8$

Comment: @Henry: But that's why I've used $2n-k$, with $k$ being the number of questions chosen to answer.

Comment: @Henry: For $p=0.9$, my suggestion gives an expected gain of $0.8$ for answering $1$ question, $1.6$ for answering $2$ questions, $2.4$ for answering $3$ questions, and $3.2$ for answering $4$ questions. So you could say that any choice of answering between $2$ and $4$ questions is good enough for passing the test. Nevertheless, answering $4$ questions would yield the highest probability (I think). So I don't quite understand what's wrong with this approach.

Comment: @Henry: OK, I think I get it (though, please read the previous two comments). We should choose the option with the highest probability of answering more questions correctly than wrongly.

Comment: Indeed.  I also think you will find choosing $2$ is never better than choosing $1$ since $p^2 \le p$, and similarly choosing $4$ is never better than choosing $3$.  Between choosing $1$ or $3$, it depends on $p \lessgtr \frac12$